# Displaying civicrm contact's fields in drupal 7 registration and profile edit

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, civicrm

I am using Drupal 7 with civicrm 4.5. I want to display the civi contact fields in drupal registration and profile forms. I used the civicrm profile to display the first name and last name fields. But i don't know how to integrate the address, phone and email fields same as civi in drupal(For ex for address with [b]Another address[/b] and [b]Location type[/b] selection boxes street address,Add link,Delete  etc). Using civicrm profile i could be able to configure Home street address etc as a individual ones. But i want as a grouped one how civi is displaying. Is there any module available for this? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please click to add your support to the [CiviCRM SE site propoasl](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm?referrer=8gfMpihOSETXeNHrjdyxXQ2) so we can have a dedicated channel for these questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For better or worse, CiviCRM profiles don't have those features for picking location type or adding indefinite numbers of addresses, etc.  They respect location type, so you could have home street address, city, state, zip, etc. fields and work street address, city, state, zip, etc., and those will hang together as two addresses.

In front-facing forms, there is a way to do this using the [Webform CiviCRM Integration](https://drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) module.  You can set up several sets of address fields and let people pick the location type for each.  You might link to a Webform page from the user form to invite people to fill out more details.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach, using native CiviCRM profiles, would be to create a CiviCRM profile for each location, including the address fields for each location, and expose all them to the Drupal registration and/or account view/edit screens. For example you could have one profile on the registration screen, and have all the others only on the account view/edit screens, thereby enabling your users, once signed up and logged in, to develop their profile.

A tad clunky perhapsjust , but it would work.